# jQuery Datepicker - Show full month names in select box

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

It's really bugging me that the jQuery datepicker has a select box for changing the month but it doesn't show the full month name (but it does in the other months).

**Screenshot:** https://i.stack.imgur.com/N1gTU.png

Is there a way to customise the datepicker to show the full month name without modifying the source code?

Comment: You know, its really hard to debug a picture...

Comment: You don't need to debug anything.  I am asking how to customise the jQuery UI datepicker.

Comment: Ok, i didnt know its an original option in datepicker, i was thinking it was a custom one, so sorry

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Maybe a little bit late but I was having the same problem at this moment and it was pretty easily fixed. Before you call the datepicker function get the monthnames array, put them in a new variable and change shortnames by calling on that variable:

```
var fullmonth_array = $.datepicker.regional['nl'].monthNames; // change 'nl' to your own language of course
$('input[name="date-of-birth"]').datepicker(
{
   changeYear               : true,
   changeMonth              : true,
   yearRange                : "-85:-18",
   maxDate                  : "-18Y",
   minDate                  : "-85Y",
   monthNamesShort          : fullmonth_array
   // other stuff
}
```

Comment: If someone encounters this, in order this to work nowadays  you should Change `$.datepicker.regional['nl'].monthNames` to `$.datepicker._defaults.monthNames`

Answer (score 9):

Even nicer solution would be to use `monthNames` from your locale object.

```
// jQuery UI datepicker
$("#datepicker").datepicker({
    monthNamesShort: $.datepicker.regional["en"].monthNames
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Dont find better way than updating UI datepicker, but that gives you the idea:

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/JgyDj/)

```
var months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
                  "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];
var uDatepicker = $.datepicker._updateDatepicker;
$.datepicker._updateDatepicker = function() {
    var ret = uDatepicker.apply(this, arguments);
    var $sel = this.dpDiv.find('select');
    $sel.find('option').each(function(i) {
        $(this).text(months[i]);
    });
    return ret;
};

$(function() {
    $("#id").datepicker({
        changeMonth: true,
        dateFormat: 'MM yy'
    });
});​
```

Comment: Thanks, this works except it's not quite correct.  The months are wrong if the select menu doesn't have 12 months in it.  For example, if the current month is December, only December will display in the select menu but it will be called "January", according to your script.  To fix, `$(this).text(months[i]);` needs to be `$(this).text(months[$(this).attr('value')]);`

Answer (score 1):

You can extend the datepicker and "override" the offending function, passing in the long names.

```
$.extend($.datepicker, {
    __base__generateMonthYearHeader: $.datepicker._generateMonthYearHeader,

    _generateMonthYearHeader: function (inst,
                                        drawMonth,
                                        drawYear,
                                        minDate,
                                        maxDate,
                                        secondary,
                                        monthNames,
                                        monthNamesShort) {
        return $.datepicker.__base__generateMonthYearHeader(
            inst,
            drawMonth,
            drawYear,
            minDate,
            maxDate,
            secondary,
            monthNames,
            monthNames)
    }
});
```

This has the benefit of displaying the full names in the drop down but allowing the formatting specified in the settings/options when the input element is set with the selected date.

Answer (score 1):

//jquery UI datepicker

Here MM show the full name of month

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker({
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            dateFormat: 'dd MM yy',
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define attribute "`monthNamesShort`" as:

```
 $(".selector").datepicker({
   monthNamesShort: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"]
 });
```